# Run Azure Automation runbook after SSIS completed loading data into Azure SQL DWH

Tags: azure, ssis, automation, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a scenario where after lift and shift load from on-premises to Azure SQL Datawarehouse is done using the on-premises SSIS, I would like to trigger the Azure Automation runbook. Is there any way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You can [deploy your package to Azure SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure) and then use [Azure Automation Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime) to trigger the package